# Get Selected Row in DataGridView not working VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, selectedindex

I have a pretty standard DataGridView and have already used

```
.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
.MultiSelect = False
```

in order ensure the entire row is selected.

Situation : I need to obtain the selected row in order to load the data in the row to another screen to "Modify" the data. I am using the following to get the Selected Row.

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
    Try
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow
            row = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            GlobalVariables.SelectedlineItemRowNo = e.RowIndex ' Or row
            MsgBox("GlobalVariables.SelectedlineItemRowNo is ---> " & GlobalVariables.SelectedlineItemRowNo)

            'textboxTst.Text = row.Cells("Description").Value.ToString
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Question : The problem is that most of the time when one clicks on the data within the DGV the code above is run and sets the e.RowIndex - BUT when I hit any white space on the row nothing happens and so results in the problem of using the previous row selected, which is in fact the wrong row.?

Any ideas would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not handle the SelectionChanged event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is DataGridView **CellClick** instead of CellContentClick. CellContentClick does not fire when white space around the cell content is clicked.

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellClick
Try
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        GlobalVariables.SelectedlineItemRowNo = e.RowIndex ' Or row
        MsgBox("GlobalVariables.SelectedlineItemRowNo is ---> " & GlobalVariables.SelectedlineItemRowNo)

        'textboxTst.Text = row.Cells("Description").Value.ToString
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about the event you're using: `CellContentClick`. Instead of it, use: `SelectionChanged`. This would be more useful for your purpose.

[SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In this event, the sender `e` stops being a cell, so you can change this access to: `yourListviewName.SelectedRows`, that gives you a `Collection` with the selected rows.

Since you have disabled `multiselect` property, you only need to access to the first item of it.

Comment: I am not sure this works. I tried Private Sub DataGridView2_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.SelectionChanged and this did not work

Comment: Have you wrote it manually? Because this `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` seems weird for me in this line. Create it by selecting the event in the top side of code view in VS.

Comment: @mond007 If you write an event handle manually make sure the method signature matches the event delegate. In this case, SelectionChanged is an [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate: `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`

Comment: Ok I understand i created it using the top side of the view in VS and is correct now i.e.     Private Sub DataGridView2_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.SelectionChanged
        Try
            If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim row As DataGridViewRow
                row = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex) BUT the e.RowIndex does not compile. Thxs

Comment: This is because the sender changed, I updated the answer @mond007

Comment: HI I tried GlobalVariables.SelectedlineItemRowNo = ataGridView2.SelectedRows and this does not compile.

Comment: Of course it doesn't @mond007, I said this is a property which returns a collection. You still have to access to the first item of it, as I said (to get the `row`. And there, you're trying to store a collection into an int var (which I don't know why do you still want to use).